# jQuery - Removing td's click event after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bind a click event to all `td`s like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#table").on("click","td",clickHandler);
});
```

How to remove a particular `clickHandler` from a clicked `td` after clicking it?

Comment: Maybe you could use off() method: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi i tried calling off inside the function clickHandler, it did not work.

Comment: You should call that outside this function!

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi i want to click the td and after the first click, remove the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want each table cell to have the click event bound to it for one click, use `.one()`:

```
$("td").one("click",function(){
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

```js
$("td").one("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
  $(this).off("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$('td').toArray().forEach(td => {
  td = $(td);
  
  td.attr('onclick', 'alert(this.id)');
});

$(document).on('click', 'td', function () {
  $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">Item 1</td>
    <td id="td2">Item 2</td>
    <td id="td3">Item 3</td>
    <td id="td4">Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My idea: setting `onclick` attribute to `td` tag, after clicking, removing the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A different approach where you don't need to add/remove `class` and also no need to modify `onclick` attribute as inline events are not recommended.

What i'm doing here is binding the click event slightly differently.

What you are doing is `$("#table").on("click", "td", clickHandler)` - it will bind event to `#table` and upon click filter it for `td`.

Now what i'm doing is `$("#table td").on("click",clickHandler)` - it will bind the event to all `td` inside `#table`. So when the click event occurs, for that particular `td` `click` can be turned off by `$(this).off("click");`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#table td").on("click",clickHandler);
});

var clickHandler = function(){
  console.log(this);
 $(this).off("click");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```